# Which of these declarations is the proper one for declaring a C function?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand the Signals and studying from various resources.

One resource I found is [this](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.choi/www/Resource/signal.pdf).

Here the declaration is as follows:

```
void (*signal(int, void (*)(int)))(int);
```

And the other one is [this](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r8932390-Can-someone-help-me-with-this-syntax-C-language).

Here the declaration is as follows:

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func) (int)))(int);
```

So side-by-side(!) they are:

```
void (*signal(int, void (*)(int)))(int);
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func) (int)))(int);
```

Which one is the proper way and why?

Comment: They appear to be the same. Can you point out the functional difference you perceive?

Comment: @Jongware I am asking about the syntax. One misses the keywords such as "sig" and "func".

Comment: @KorayTugay: Those aren't keywords. Keywords are thinks like `if` and `return`.

Comment: Those are not "syntax". Check your course book on "function declarations" (and on "keywords in C").

Comment: @Jongware I tought function declaration was syntax.

Comment: It is. Both are "function declarations", both are valid, both are the same. That is why I said that they appear the same to me (and your compiler ought to do so as well).

Comment: @Jongware Well I did not know C allowed both syntax for declaring functions, hence the confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Part of your confusion likely stems from the fact that the second is a mix of supplied and omitted parameter names; at least the first one omits all parameter names consistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are the same.

One declaration happens to give them names to aid in understanding. The other is less helpful.

The ones with names are trying to be self documenting

Comment: So when declaring a function in C, I can avoid the variable names? Only include the types? Like int myFunc(int,int,int) ? I did not know that, hence the confusion. Thanks.

Comment: .. But put in variable names - helps in understanding

Comment: Yes definetly.. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In a function type, parameters may but do not need to have names. There is nothing you can do with the names, and they serve as documentation at best:

```
typedef bool(*checker_v1)(int);
typedef bool(*checker_v2)(int arg);    // optional parameter name

checker_v1 f = is_even;
checker_v2 g = is_odd;
f = g;                    // f and g have the same type

typedef bool(fchecker)(int);   // also OK, fchecker* == checker_v1 == checker_v2
```

Function pointers can be the type of function parameters:

```
void process(int n, checker_v1 f, fchecker* g, bool(*h)(int pointless))
{
    if (f(n)) { do_a(); }
    if (g(n)) { do_b(); }
    if (h(n)) { do_c(); }
}
```

In the final example, note that the name of the parameter of the type of the fourth parameter type of `process` is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

```
void foo(int);
```

is the same as

```
void foo(int x);
          // ^^ name of the argument.
```

In the same vein,

```
void (*signal(int, void (*)(int)))(int);
```

is the same as

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func) (int)))(int);
                           // ^^^^ name of the argument.
```